# Overlapping or sliding interval matching

Tags: r, paired-comparisons, matching, paired-data

So I want to conduct a matched case-control study.
One of the variables I want to match on is continuous variable, lets say age. I have converted this to categorical variable [17-19],[20-36],[37+]. This will return a greater number of pairs then if we just treat age as a continuous function.

But I want to do not exclude someone who is say 32 to be paired with someone with similar characteristics who is 37.

I am using the `Matching` package in `R` to do the matching, and if I use the `GenMatch` function, the pairs are only returned that appear in the same category.

Does one know how to introduce sliding pairing in addition to the categorical values.

Lets take for example the

```
library(Matching)
data(lalonde)

lalonde$AGE_cat <- with(lalonde, ifelse(age < 20, 1, ifelse(age > 36, 3, 2)))

attach(lalonde)

lalonde$ID <- 1:length(lalonde$age)
```

and then we introduce the age categorical, as described above. We want to use this as a matching variable but also account for its continous function.

Could one introduce a function so that for the values near the limits of the AGE_cat be paired +- xx years??